# Orthographic perspective map ̀problems

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, orthographic, putimagedata

I was trying to make a sphere using some [data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_map_projection) I found on Wikipedia about the Orthographic projection of a map and there's been something that has been keeping me busy for some time. When I run the project, on the center of the sphere there apears one pixel that is colored in a wrong way when changing the longitude. I tried to solve this problem in a lot of ways like using **if**s to separe the wrong pixel from the rest of them or delaying the longitude of the wrong pixel but neither of those worked, can somebody help me?

```js
var Canvas = document.getElementById("MainCanvas");
Canvas.style.imageRendering = "pixelated";
var Context = Canvas.getContext("2d");
var Sphere = {
    radius: 80,
    lat: 0,
    long: 0
}

Render();
function Render()
{
    let ImgData = Context.createImageData(Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
    //Sphere.lat += 0.02;
    Sphere.long += 0.01;
    document.getElementById("Display").innerHTML = Sphere.long;
    for(var y = 0; y != Canvas.height; y++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x != Canvas.width; x++)
        {
            /*Get the true position*/
            let TrueX = x - Canvas.width / 2;
            let TrueY = Canvas.height / 2 - y;
            /*Get the distance*/
            let Dist = Math.sqrt(TrueX * TrueX + TrueY * TrueY);
            if(Dist < Sphere.radius)
            {
                let C, CurrLat, CurrLong;
                /*Get the depth of a sphere point*/
                C = Math.asin(Dist / Sphere.radius);
                /*Color the pixel*/
                if(TrueX === 0 && TrueY === 0)
                {
                    CurrLong = (Sphere.long) % (Math.PI);
                    CurrLat = (Sphere.lat) % (2*Math.PI);
                }
                else
                {
                    /*Get the latitude (Clamped the value to 0 → π)*/
                    CurrLong = (Math.asin(Math.cos(C)*Math.sin(Sphere.long)+(TrueY*Math.sin(C)*Math.cos(Sphere.long))/Dist)) % Math.PI;
                    /*And the longitude (Clamped the value to 0 → 2π)*/
                    CurrLat = (Sphere.lat + Math.atan2((TrueX*Math.sin(C)), (Dist*Math.cos(C)*Math.cos(Sphere.long) - (TrueY*Math.sin(C)*Math.sin(Sphere.long))))) % (2*Math.PI);
                }
                
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)]   = (CurrLong / (Math.PI)) * 255;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+1] = 0;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+2] = (CurrLat / (Math.PI * 2)) * 255;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+3] = 255;
            }
            else
            {
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)]   = 200;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+1] = 200;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+2] = 200;
                ImgData.data[4*((y * Canvas.width)+x)+3] = 255;
            }
        }   
    }
    Context.putImageData(ImgData, 0, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(Render);
}
```

```css
#MainCanvas
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://c.tenor.com/k9yAts9ymaIAAAAM/loading-load.gif");
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
#Display
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="MainCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
        <div id="Display"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I understand it. The value of longitude must be between -π/2 and π/2